# tint out a picture to a flag but got errors: cannot resolve to variable

Tags: java, variables, pixel, tint

I have this as an assignment to tint out a picture into kinda like a Dutch flag. But i have a lot of troubles figuring out the way to divide the height into sections. When I did it like below I got lots of errors that mostly says "cannot resolve to a variable".
Here's my code:

```
/* Assignment 3, Part 2 - Go Dutch! */

public class Assignment3Part2
{
//
  public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    String filename;
    if (args.length > 0) {
       // got a filename passed into program as a parameter
       // don't change this part of the code needed by TA for grading
       filename = args[0];      
       System.out.println("Filename passed in: " + filename);

    } else {
       // ask user for a picture
       filename = FileChooser.pickAFile();
       System.out.println("User picked file: " + filename);
    }
    Picture pic = new Picture(filename);   // Picture to modify
    //
    pic.show();             // Show the original picture
    Thread.sleep(1000);     //  Pause for 1 second.  You can pause for less if you like

    Pixel[] pixelArray = pic.getPixels();

    // TODO:

      for(int x = 0; x < pic.getWidth(); x++);
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < pic.getHeight(); y++);
        {
          int h = pic.getHeight();
          if ( y <=(h/3))
          {

              value = pic.getOrange();
              value = (int)(value*1.5);
              pic.setOrange(value);
          }
          if ( y > (h/3)&& y < (2*h/3))
          {

              value = pic.getWhite();
              value = (int)(value*1.5);
              pic.setWhite(value);
          }
          else {

              value = pic.getGreen();
              value = (int)(value*1.5);
              pic.setGreen(value);
          }

        }

      }
    }

    pic.repaint();
  }  // End of main
}  // End of Class
```

And here's the errors the system gives:

```
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 34]
Error: y cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 37]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 37]
Error: The method getOrange() is undefined for the type Picture
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 38]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 38]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 39]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 41]
Error: y cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 41]
Error: y cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 44]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 44]
Error: The method getWhite() is undefined for the type Picture
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 45]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 45]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 46]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 50]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 50]
Error: The method getGreen() is undefined for the type Picture
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 51]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 51]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 52]
Error: value cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 60]
Error: Syntax error on token "repaint", Identifier expected after this token
File: C:\Users\nhock\Desktop\School Work\UNCC Fall 2018\1212\ITIS_1212\bookClasses\Assignment3Part2.java  [line: 62]
Error: Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

Can someone explain and also help me solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon directly after for loop conditions. In Java ‘;’ tells that instruction ends. As a result code after semicolon doesn’t belong to for loop.

```
for(int x = 0; x < pic.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < pic.getHeight(); y++) {
```